# C# objects and code examples

Tags: c#

I am new to .NET 3/3.5 (C#) Programming. It may be simple for you but not for me.
I have a task to executing stored procedure from c# application, using command and it returns 3 different data tables proc is already done in sql 2005,but I want to know how to get data in c#. exactly need  c# code how to handle data tables form the result set,if result set returns more than one datatable.
Thanks

Comment: I suggest you post your attempt so far...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [SqlDataAdapter.Fill()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill.aspx) method to fill a [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx). This way you can access the multiple result tables using this -

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Column X"];
ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["Column Y"];
ds.Tables[2].Rows[0]["Column Z"];
...
```

Or, you can use a [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) (which is faster if you want to process your data in a forward-only fashion). For reading the records of the first result set, you can iterate a `while` loop and call the [SqlDataReader.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx) method.

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    //Process the first result set here.
}
```

For fetching the next result set, you call the [SqlDataReader.NextResult()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx) method.

```
reader.NextResult();
while(reader.Read())
{
    //Process the next result set here.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use NextResult in case of ExecuteReader

```
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.HasRows)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", reader.GetName(0),reader.GetName(1));

         while (reader.Read())
         {
             Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                        reader.GetString(1));
         }
         reader.NextResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

So you already have the DataSet? If so, it's easy. You get at a particular table using the `Tables` property, e.g.

```
DataTable users = dataSet.Tables["users"];
```

If that's not what you mean, please clarify the question.

Comment: I guess, he means to ask how to handle multiple result-sets returned from an SQL query using ADO.NET.

Comment: But we really need to know how far he's got before we can help further - if he's already got a DataSet, then explaining what to do with a DataReader doesn't help, and vice versa.

Comment: Hmmm. You are right. But, I answered on the basis of what I inferred from the question. I thought that he was stuck on HOW to get the multiple result set in his app, and use them; I showed him two ways in which this can be done. And btw, he is confused between datatable/result set, he should have referred it to result set actually.

Comment: Right - if he'd said that, I'd have given an answer more like yours. I inferred that the result sets were already there, and just needed to be extracted. This is the problem with very vague questions :( Anyway, I'm glad it looks like you've sorted him out now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim db As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(ApplicationStringResource.DbConn)
    Dim cmd As DbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(DbStoreProc.GetFeeCodeStoreProc)
    Dim sReader As SqlDataReader = db.ExecuteReader(cmd)
    Try
        While sReader.Read()
            Dim feeCode As New FeeCode()
            With feeCode
                .FeeCode = sReader("FeeCode")
                .Description = sReader("Description")
            End With
            feeCodeList.Add(feeCode)
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    Finally
        sReader.Close()
    End Try
    Return feeCodeList
```

I use MS Enterprise Library and the above is an code block that I use to get the data via SQLDataReader.

Comment: That's not C#. The questioner wants it in C#, not VB.Net